# Magento Round off currency conversions

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, currency

I have to keep USD as base currency to enable PayPal but I have kept default display currency as INR. Now conversion rate of 45rs per USD give me nasty decimal INR prices, I wana get rid of that, Magento must be using some function to convert price from base currency to INR while showing up INR prices everywhere, What is that function and How can I modify it to always give round off values??

I found :

```
$price = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($tax-&gt;getPrice($product, $product->getFinalPrice(), false), $fromCur, $toCur);
```

Is this the function Magento itself uses to convert prices in different currencies, If it is where it is defined?

Comment: Thanks for telling me , will do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The currency conversion is performed by `Mage_Directory_Model_Currency` in the following method.

```
public function convert($price, $toCurrency=null)
{
    if (is_null($toCurrency)) {
        return $price;
    }
    elseif ($rate = $this->getRate($toCurrency)) {
        return $price*$rate;
    }

    throw new Exception(Mage::helper('directory')->__('Undefined rate from "%s-%s".', $this->getCode(), $toCurrency->getCode()));
}
```

You could create an `app/code/local` version of this file, or write your own module and rewrite the core.

Make sure you test this **very carefully** in your dev server and Paypal sandbox, since Paypal will reject any transactions that have errors!

Comment: day Thanks Jonathan, I will try this and let you know, As you said I can create a local copy in app/code/local, will just creating a local copy start Magento to call this file instead of core file or I have to do something else as well.

Comment: just placing the file into app/code/local with the exact same path should work without any other config.